# Where can I download Xulrunner 1.9.2.10 for Debian?

Tags: xul, xulrunner

It need to be 1.9.2.10 or older.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to go back to the Karmic packages (for v. 1.8.1.16 of xulrunner), which you can find here:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/devel/xulrunner

You *may* have trouble working around it's myriad dependencies, however.

Answer (score 0):

Las time I check synaptic I have 1.9.2.12 Installed (I use Lucid).

Alternatively, you can build from source. [this page](http://www.indexdata.com/cf-doc/installation.html#xulrunner-1.9.2-debian-lenny) may help you. But if you strictly need 1.9.2.10, I don't know where to find it (1.9.2.12 is the latest source release [listed on download page](http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/))